# Nuxt3 api Cors erorr

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How can I solve CORS errors in nuxt3. I'm using Axios and also tried useFetch but didn't work. Also tried server-middlware but it keeps sending the js file , I don't fully  understand it

Comment: Please make a search before posting. Otherwise, give us some context that is specific to your use case.

Comment: @kissu I already scoured the web for this, I didn't get any solution otherwise I wouldn`t be asking here.

Comment: Asking here casually how to fix an issue will not work. Gotta put some effort into your question as everybody else. We don't know what you tried so far, nor what is not working. You have plenty of answers (not all good tho) in the given link. Without knowing your issue, we can't give you a fix.